# Rails group_by_day working with specific day of the week "friday"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Events has people through spectators working.
In events there is a date selector saving to a date column. 
I'm trying to .count all events that happen on lets say Friday, and figure out how many spectators on average go to friday events.

I just want to spit out a number on the view like a stat.

I was trying to use groupdate gem because it seamed simple.

In my stat_controller

```
@average = Event.group_by_day(:date).count
```

Can I get some sort of .wday in this to group all friday together?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try `Event.where("extract(dow from date) = ?", 5)`

Here 5 means Friday.

**UPDATE:**

```
friday_event_ids = Event.where("extract(dow from date) = ?", 5).pluck(:id)
spectators_in_friday_events = Spectator.where(event_id: friday_event_ids)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you!  now if I'm getting the count for all friday events.. how do I average how many spectators we have on friday events?

Comment: @Jrinard please provide more details on how your database associate events with spectators.

Comment: Event has many people through spectators. 
Can I do something like Event.spectators.where("extract(dow from date) = ?", 5)